# Javascript sort array based on certain string

Tags: javascript

Basicly i'm trying to sort an array based of a certain string match.
I want qualifier === 'oip' to sort to the top

```
[
 {
  qualifier: 'abc',
 },
 {
  qualifier: 'oip'
 }
]
```

How would I do that with `x.sort((a,b) =>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
x.sort((a,b) => a === 'oip'? 1 : -1)
```

You can read more about [sort here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

> If a and b are two elements being compared, then:
>
> - If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b (i.e. a comes first).
> - If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to an index lower than a (i.e. b comes first).
> - compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.

This answer worked for the example stated by OP. However, to be more complete (thanks for pointing it out [@Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993007/javascript-sort-array-based-on-certain-string#comment96743510_54993021)), here is a full version:

```
x = [
 {qualifier: 'abc'},
 {qualifier: 'oip'},
 {qualifier: 'def'},
 {qualifier: 'gij'},
 {qualifier: 'oip'},
];

y = x.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.qualifier === b.qualifier && a.qualifier === 'oip') {
    return 0;
  } else if (a.qualifier === 'oip') {
    return -1;
  } else if (b.qualifier === 'oip') {
    return 1;
  }else {
    return a.qualifier > b.qualifier? 1 : -1;
  }
});
```

Comment: I think that gets the ordering backwards; `"oip"` is supposed to sort to the *top*.

Comment: Just tested it on chrome and "oip" appears on top. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vz9jodqc/)

Comment: Not in Firefox.  Think about it: your code says that if the first entry **is** "oip", it should sort **after** the second one. Really a sort comparator should always check both arguments; if both were "oip" your comparator  could cause strange behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply other type of ordering (`ascending` or `descending`) to the rest of the elements and have the elements with qualifier equals to `oip` at top, then you can do something like this (In the example, ascending order is applied to the rest of the elements):

```js
const input = [
 {qualifier: 'abc', id: "1"},
 {qualifier: 'oip', id: "2"},
 {qualifier: 'def', id: "3"},
 {qualifier: 'oip', id: "4"},
];

input.sort(({qualifier: q1}, {qualifier: q2}) =>
{      
    if (q1 === 'oip' && q2 === 'oip')
        return 0;
    else if (q1 === 'oip')
        return -1;
    else if (q2 === 'oip')
        return 1;
    else
        return q1.localeCompare(q2);
});

console.log(input);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: what if they're *both* "oip"?

Comment: @Pointy it will be catched by the first `if` sentence so the element holding `q1` will go first. You can explicilty declare another condition that check if both are equals to `oip` and return `0`, but in my opinion that will not change the final output (unless i'm missing something).

Comment: Well personally I think it's bad practice to not guarantee that a sort comparator will return the same answer when the same two elements are compared, *regardless* of the order they're passed (because you can't predict that; two elements from the array might be "a" and "b" on one call but "b" and "a" on another).